# Disabling/Pause database replication using ML-Gradle

Tags: gradle, marklogic, marklogic-8, ml-gradle

I want to disable the **Database Replication** from the replica cluster in MarkLogic 8 using ML-Gradle. After updating the configurations, I also want to **re-enable** it.
There are tasks for enabling and disabling flexrep in ML Gradle. But I couldn't found any such thing for Database Replication. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

ml-gradle uses the Management API to handle configuration changes. Database Replication is controlled by sending a [PUT command to /manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]/properties](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]/properties). Update your ml-config/databases/content-database.json file ([example that does not include that property](https://github.com/rjrudin/ml-gradle/blob/master/examples/sample-project/src/main/ml-config/databases/content-database.json)) to include `database-replication`, including `replication-enabled: true`.

To see what that object should look like, you can send a [GET request to the properties endpoint](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]/properties).

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own command to set replication-enabled - see https://github.com/rjrudin/ml-gradle/wiki/Writing-your-own-management-task

I'll also add a ticket for making official commands - e.g. mlEnableReplication and mlDisableReplication, with those defaulting to the content database, and allowing for any database to be specified.